# how to draw Multiple separated surfaces in 1 data frame using plotly python?

Tags: python, plotly, surface

I have multiple separate surfaces like below image:
[image: What I Need]

I have **their data in one data frame**. How can I draw them? **would you share Plotly python code to show me how can I draw them without using loops?**

Comment: Can you include a sample of your DataFrame? How are the different shapes distinguished from one another in the DataFrame?

Comment: @DerekO Thanks for your contribution. Using Scatter3D for drawing lines, you can simply draw many separated lines only adding 'None' between their coordinates. I'm searching for such approach for separated surfaces on plotly!